# How to get payment response callback to my backend while using all-in-one sdk on Android

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions, paytm

I am trying to setup paytm in my Flutter app, I create the txn token on firebase cloud function in which the callback URL I pass it is paytm's static url, https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=order_id. While the payment flow is working on the client side, I'm not sure how do I get back the response of the payment ON MY BACKEND once the transaction is complete (succeeded or failed)? Do I set up a polling just after I create the transaction token to call the order status API? I tried setting up a webhook in the dashboard > Developer > Webhooks > payment notification, but no requests are made from the paytm servers after the transaction (same goes for refund webhooks).

Comment: Were you able to get trigger transaction or refund webhook? Any solution you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

There is a one plugin available for doing this called [paytmkaro](https://pub.dev/packages/paytmkaro) you can use this but it's only work with production keys.

Before starting upload the server side code on server which is available on their documentation which is available [here](https://github.com/codersanket/Paytm-Server-code) please don't make any changes on server side code it's used to generate a txn token on paytm server.

Change the minimum sdk version to 19

and just copy paste this code

```
` try {
  PaytmResponse paymentResponse = await _paytmKaro.startTransaction(
    url: serverside code url e.g. https://arcane-temple-61754.herokuapp.com/intiateTansection.php,
    mid: your Production merchant id,
    mkey: your merchant key,
    customerId:customer id (must be unique for every customer),
    amount: transection amount,
    orderId: Order Id (Order id must be unique Everytime for every order),
  );

  if(paymentResponse.status=="TXN_SUCCESS"){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>txnSuccessful(paytmResponse: paymentResponse,)));
  }
  else if(paymentResponse.status=="TXN_FAILURE"){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>txnFailed(paytmResponse: paymentResponse,)));
  }
} 
catch(e){
  print(e);
  key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())));      // platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.'
}`
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Please raise a query to paytm -> Open paytm developer portal than go into the **FAQ** section and click on **send a Query**.